# print statement not showing any output in terminal - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I got a problem with my print statement on my for loop not showing up any output. (I used Jupyter Notebook inside my VScode)

But when I try to run another print statement on another block, it works perfectly fine.

Here's the complete code from the beginning:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://google.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5'
}

url = ('https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/restaurants?page=1')
page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
main = soup.find_all('div', class_='results')

for m in main:
    restaurant_name = m.find('a', class_='business-name').text

    print(restaurant_name) # this one doesn't work.**

msg = 'Hello World!'
print(msg) # this one works fine.**
```

My desired results, it should print a list of restaurant name in the terminal.

Comment: then inspect the content of `main`

Comment: there are no `div` tags with a class `results`

Answer (score 1):

The only change that you have to make this work is to change the class in your div from `results` to `result` without the "s". The rest is fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is probably happening because selector mismatch. Websites often update their HTML structure, so what worked previously might not work now.